# semi-transparent background for MathGL plots

Tags: c++, plot, mathgl

Is it possible to make MathGL produce an image where the background is semi-transparent (like 50%) and the foreground elements are opaque?

How do I specify semi-transparent backgrounds in C++ for rendering-to-memory images?

Comment: I have no experience with MathGL, but it may be beneficial to post how you would create an image with an opaque background.

Comment: "Finally, you can specify RGB or RGBA values of a color using format ‘{xRRGGBB}’ or ‘{xRRGGBBAA}’ correspondingly. For example, ‘{xFF9966}’ give you melone color." So you can define a color with an alpha channel. FF would be opaque, and 00 would be transparent. [Source of quote](http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/doc_en/Color-styles.html#Color-styles)

Comment: I received an email from the author and he said that it is not currently (v2.2.2.1) possible to make a semi-transparent background, but he is confident he can add support for that feature.